# Given a collection of pixels, how to deduce the flux from them?

Tags: star, telescope, observational-astronomy, exoplanet, light

I've obtained the coordinates of brightest pixels from different images (.fits files) using Python. I want to get the flux of each pixel. How do I go about finding out the flux?

Comment: link only: http://www.stsci.edu/hst/HST_overview/documents/datahandbook/intro_ch35.html

Comment: What do you know about your detector?